# change css href attributes to multiple html pages onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I would like to have users choose a colour theme for their experience on my site. I have created different themed external css files and have created a function to successfully switch between all the colour options I have created.

The only problem is when I click on a link to another page on the site the theme returns to the default colour in which I created the page.

Is there a way to dynamically change the href attribute of every html page so the css colour file is changed on every page. Or would I need cookies to remember this? I have not learned about cookies yet but wondered if this could be a function.

Below is my code which changes between each colour fine on that page, but only on that page.

HTML:
    
    
    
    

    
        Orange Theme
        Purple Theme
        Red Theme

Javascript:
    
        function setStyleSheet(url) {
        var stylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet");
            stylesheet.setAttribute('href', url);
        }

I have the required css files saved externally. Any help would be gratefully welcome. Thanks.

Comment: set a cookie, check to see if the cookie exists, set the stylesheet based on that cookie.

Comment: You need to set a cookie or some localStorage to store the theme the user has chosen. You can't easily do this by merely traversing pages.

Comment: do u want to know how to change the href attribute of the link tag on clicking on a link(<a> tag)?

Answer (score 0):

*Ideally* you would use cookies, but if you really *really* wanted to do it without cookies you could try running something like:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var existingHref = links[i].href;
    links[i].href += (links[i].href.indexOf("?") + 1 ? "&" : "?") + "theme=" + encodeURIComponent(theme);
}
```

(Untested code, and there are a few other edge cases you would want to check for, but the general idea is there)

This would update each link on the page, adding a `theme=[theme]` property to its URL, which you could then load in later pages by parsing [`window.location.search`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp):

```
function getTheme() {
    if (window.location.search.split("theme=").length < 2) return null;
    return window.location.search.split("theme=")[1].split("&")[0];
}
```

Note when I say "ideally" I really mean that you should be using cookies - they were made and are used almost exactly for this purpose, you don't have to deal with sketchy edge cases like if there's already a `theme` in the URL or if it's going to another domain that also uses `theme` in the URL, if you change pages with Javascript it will still work, etc. - but I believe this method should work as well.

Comment: Hey, if you go for one-line-monster-statements, at least make’m short as possible (disregarding variable naming): `links[i].href += (links[i].href.indexOf("?") + 1 ? "&" : "?") + "theme=" + theme;` ;-) Also, DRY.

Comment: (Depending on what values `theme` will actually contain, we might want to throw in `encodeURIComponent` for the parameter value.)